# How to define constants in Python based on if/else without pyright warning

Tags: python, pyright

I'm attempting a fairly typical `if/else` -> `CONSTANT = ...` pattern in python but getting a pyright error that "... is constant (because it is uppercase) and cannot be redefined" ([reportConstantRedefinition](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#reportConstantRedefinition)). While this is not a syntax error, I'm trying to understand how to avoid the pyright warning and -- *more importantly* -- what the proper pattern is.

My constant is defined based on an if statement. E.g.:

```
if os.getenv('DEBUG'):
  API_HOST = 'http://STAGING/'
else:
  API_HOST = 'http://PROD/'
```

It's on the last line that pyright gives the error "*"API_HOST" is constant (because it is uppercase) and cannot be redefined*".

I've always thought that was a valid pattern. Is there a better way to do that which isn't just a way to outwit pyright? Why does pyright think I should do?
E.g., `APIHOST = 'x' if os.getenv('DEBUG') else 'y'` would work but is harder to read and not scalable.

(I also tried to predefine the variable (`API_HOST: str`) so that it's clear that it's not unbound (which it can't be) but that just gives me a "redefine" error on *both* lines.)

Comment: This looks like a bug in pyright, it should realize that the `if` and `else` are mutually exclusive, so you're not changing a constant.

Comment: I tried finding it in the pyright issues, but couldn't. I suggest you report it as a bug.

Comment: `API_HOST = 'http://STAGING/' if os.getenv('DEBUG') else 'http://PROD/'`

Answer (score 1):

According to one maintainer of pyright this behaviour is by design.

They say:

> A constant (by definition) can have only one statically-determined
> value. If it can have different values at runtime based on dynamic
> behaviours, then it's a variable, not a constant.

I reported this as a bug, but it was closed with that reasoning:
https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/5265

(I would not agree because than there would be no constants in Python because no object is determined statically in Python. I would define a constant as a variable that does not get modified after definition).